BouncyCastle version conflict FIPS C#
I'm trying to work with FIPS in a CMAC function but I'm running into version conflicts. I have the regular BouncyCastle.Cryptography v2.0.0.0 referenced and bc-fips-1.0.2.dll V1.0.2 reference in Visual Studio 2022, .NET framework 4.8, C#. The bc-fips-1.0.2 is reference because it has "BouncyCastle.Crypto.Fips".
There are essentially two conflicts one with 'SecureRandom' and the other 'CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService'.
Error: 'CryptoServicesRegistrar' exists in both 'BouncyCastle.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=072edcf4a5328938' and 'bc-fips-1.0.2, Version=1.0.2.0
Anyone know a workaround or fix for this?
I think you for your assistance in advance.

This question is similar to: Potential issues of using the FIPS and non-FIPS versions of the BouncyCastle library in the same project. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes ,thank you, I've read that one already before making this post. First problem is its Java, and they are talking about non-FIPS. I'm referring to two dlls that don't work together. Also, the question does not present a fix.

You stated that you are using both NuGet package BouncyCastle.Cryptography. If one clicks on Project Website, one is taken to BouncyCastle.org which is where one finds bc-fips-1.0.2.dll - information about FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standards) can be found here. While this doesn't necessarily mean that they both use the same namespace, the error message indicates that they do.

The type 'CryptoServicesRegistrar' exists in both
'BouncyCastle.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=072edcf4a5328938' and 'bc-fips-1.0.2, Version=1.0.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

If using Visual Studio, another way one can see the namespaces is to use Object Browser.

Click View
Select Solution Explorer
In Solution Explorer, expand References
Right-click bc-fips-1.0.2 and select View in Object Browser
Expand bc-fips-1.0.2
Expand Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
Select CryptoServiceRegistrar

While the Object Browser is open:

Expand BouncyCastle.Cryptography
Expand Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
Select CryptoServiceRegistrar

This issue is described in this post.
One possibility is to create two class libraries that use unique namespaces - one class library that contains your methods that use the FIPS compliant version (ie: bc-fips-1.0.2.dll) and a different class library that contains your methods that use the non-FIPS compliant version (ie: BouncyCastle.Cryptography).
A more desirable option may be to use an alias in the .csproj file as described in this post.
Note: Ensure that you've configured NuGet Package Manager to use PackageReference in Visual Studio (before adding NuGet package(s)):

In Visual Studio menu, click Tools
Select Options...
Expand NuGet Package Manager
Select General
Under Package Management, for Default package management format, select PackageReference.
Click OK



Download/install the NuGet package for BouncyCastle.Cryptography.

Download bc-fips.dll from here.

Add project reference to bc-fips.dll (Project => Add Reference... => Browse => click browse button...)

Either unload your project or close Visual Studio.

Modify your project file (.csproj). If you've unloaded your project in Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, double-click <project name>. If you've closed Visual Studio, then open the .csproj file using Notepad.
Change from:
<PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle.Cryptography" >

To:
<PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle.Cryptography" Aliases="NonFips">

Note: Aliases is only available for NuGet packages. See PackageReference Aliases for more information. Change NonFips to whatever name you like.

Either reload your project or open your project again in Visual Studio.

Before any using directives add the following:
extern alias NonFips;


Build/rebuild your project.

When using methods from the non-FIPS compliant version (ie: BouncyCastle.Cryptography) ensure that you use the alias (ie: NonFips or whatever you've named the alias) along with the fully-qualified namespace for the method such as:
NonFips.Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.GetSecureRandom();



Additional Resources:

Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference


Thank you for the detailed description. It certainly helps when you knew to this type of version conflict and the use of aliases. I installed "BouncyCastle.Cryptography" via NuGet packages, opened the  (.csproj), but there is no "PackageReference" only ""

@DemarcPoint: I've added additional information to the post - ensure that NuGet Package Manager is set to use PackageReference instead of Packages.config.

Well, I thought I almost had it. I was able to configure the project as instructed "PackageReference" and added the "extern alias NonFips;". However, I ran into the same type of error  being in both dlls, Bouncy Castle and bc-fips-1.0.2.
As this didn't work out totally for me I downloaded the source code for bc-fips-1.0.2.dll, I changed the namespace but this caused a checksum problem.
It's starting to look like I'm going to have to do the fips-1.0.2.dll as a standalone project which is not really what I wanted to do.

@DemarcPoint: BouncyCastle.Cryptography shows _vulnerabilities for versions < 2.4, so you should use version 2.4. Everything in my post was tested with version 2.4. Please provide an update to the end of your post that shows the code that you're using as well as the contents of the .csproj file.

I suspect that was the problem. I installed BouncyCastle.Cryptography v2.4.0 and the "PackageReference" worked just perfectly so I'll use this procedure. However, as for the checksum problem, I you cannot change the namespace of (bc-fips-1.0.2.dll) which will cause it to have an internal checksum validation problem. I think this has something to do with FIPS compliance. I appreciate your detailed explanation and help. Thank you much.
